# Switch autocompletion for enum in Visual Assist or Vanilla Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-assist

Is there anyway to have a switch expand with all the values of an enum using Visual Assist or Vanilla Visual Studio?. The included snipsets just insert a basic switch with just a default entry. I'm using last visual studio 2013 update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS 2013 can build a switch statement for an enum using a default snippet. (Note: use a default VS snippet, not a VA Snippet.)

As you type "swit", accept the suggested code snippet from VS. Replace "switch_on" with your enum and press Enter. Your statement will expand. (You need two Enters if one selected your enum from a listbox.)

[image: select the default VS snippet for switch]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. More precisely, it worked once and then two times it did not. VS2015. Any idea?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I have the same issue. Sometimes it works and it's great. Sometimes the option just doesn't show up. The other answer by sean-e below worked for me in all cases.

Answer (score 7):

After the switch has initially been generated, if you add new enum values, then you can use the [Add Missing Case Statements](http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W644) command in Visual Assist to populate the switch statement with the new values (`shift+alt+q, m`).

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2015, the auto-completion of switch cases is defeated if the discriminator is declared with const as in this example:

```
auto const enu = static_cast<MediaType>(discriminant);
```

Remove const, and voila--it works again!

(Then you can put the const back in, if you wish.)

Comment: Thanks! It still seems like it works the same in VS 2019.